# I am able to access a property even if i am not loading it inside my CSOM code

Tags: development, csom

I have the following code, to get a list item based on the ID and load specific properties only, as follow:-

```
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
                        camlQuery.ViewXml = string.Format("<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Number'>{0}</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>", listItemID);
                        ListItemCollection collListItem = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Project Update System").GetItems(camlQuery);
                        context.Load(collListItem);
                        context.Load(collListItem,
                         items => items.Include(
                             item => item.Id,
                             item => item["ProjectDescription"],
                             item => item["ProjectOMSNumber"],
                             item => item["ProjectDateSinged"],
                             item => item["ProjectManHoursEstimated"],
                             item => item["ProjectStage"]
                             ));
                        context.ExecuteQuery();
                        context.Load(collListItem);

                        foreach (ListItem i in collListItem)
                        {
                            f (i["ProjectSDNumber"] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(i["ProjectSDNumber"].ToString()))
                            {
```

Now i thought that my above code will raise an error since i am accessing a property named `ProjectSDNumber` which is not been loaded.. but my code worked without errors. so can i know what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line is redundant and load all items properties:

```
  context.Load(collListItem);
```

Comment: ok thanks for the info